# SSLCertificateKeyFile: file 'ssl-cert-snakeoil.key' does not exist or is empty - Docker image with PHP, Apache and Self Signed Certifcate

Tags: php, docker, apache, ssl

I'm trying to extend the docker image: `php:8.1.2-apache` to install self-signed SSL certificate.

This is the complete Dockerfile

```bash
FROM php:8.1.2-apache

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

ENV APACHE_CONFDIR /etc/apache2

RUN apt-get update

# 1. development packages
RUN apt-get install -y \
    git \
    zip \
    curl \
    sudo \
    unzip \
    libicu-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    g++


# apache configs + document root
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf


# 4. start with base php config, then add extensions
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"


RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-webp --with-jpeg && \
    docker-php-ext-install \
    bz2 \
    intl \
    iconv \
    bcmath \
    opcache \
    calendar \
    pdo_mysql \
    zip \ 
    gd \
    exif


# 5. install pecl packages
RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
    && rm -rf /tmp/pear \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis


# 6. composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer


# 8. we need a user with the same UID/GID with host user
# so when we execute CLI commands, all the host file's ownership remains intact
# otherwise command from inside container will create root-owned files and directories
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u 1000 -d /home/devuser devuser
RUN mkdir -p /home/devuser/.composer && \
    chown -R devuser:devuser /home/devuser


# PHP files should be handled by PHP, and should be preferred over any other file type
RUN { \
    echo '<FilesMatch \.php$>'; \
    echo '\tSetHandler application/x-httpd-php'; \
    echo '</FilesMatch>'; \
    echo; \
    echo 'DirectoryIndex disabled'; \
    echo 'DirectoryIndex index.php index.html'; \
    echo; \
    echo '<Directory ${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}>'; \
    echo '\tOptions -Indexes'; \
    echo '\tAllowOverride All'; \
    echo '</Directory>'; \
    echo; \
    echo 'SetEnvIf x-forwarded-proto https HTTPS=on'; \
    } | tee "$APACHE_CONFDIR/conf-available/docker-php.conf" \
    && a2enconf docker-php


# Install Nodejs
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | sudo -E bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs

# SSL
USER root
RUN openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem -subj "/C=AT/ST=Vienna/L=Vienna/O=Security/OU=Development/CN=example.com"
RUN a2ensite default-ssl
RUN a2enmod ssl
# mod_rewrite for URL rewrite and mod_headers for .htaccess extra headers like Access-Control-Allow-Origin-
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers


USER devuser

# Finally start script
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c" , "apache2-foreground"]
```

I added these lines to the Docker File

```bash
RUN openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem -subj "/C=AT/ST=Vienna/L=Vienna/O=Security/OU=Development/CN=example.com"
RUN a2ensite default-ssl
RUN a2enmod ssl
```

But the conatiner is stopping with this error:

```bash
AH00526: Syntax error on line 33 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:
SSLCertificateKeyFile: file '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key' does not exist or is empty
```

I'm very confused why I'm getting this error :(
Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have openssl installed in the apt-get section?

I replaced my old implementation of SSL cert (from php 7.4 docker image) which was copying `ssl-cert-snakeoil.key` which did not exist, and instead doing it this way:

```
# SSL
RUN a2enmod ssl \
    && a2ensite default-ssl \
    && openssl req -subj '/CN=example.com/O=My Company Name LTD./C=US' -new -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem

EXPOSE 443
```

I took inspiration from this source: https://gitlab.univ-lorraine.fr/canals5/docker-php/-/blob/master/php/8.1/Dockerfile